# Pinescript Warning of only support to Simple Integer and asking to eliminate the Series Integer

Tags: integer, pine-script, series, offset, pine-script-v5

I want consider all Bars are Valid Bar; except "In Bar" for my Analysis. Among all Valid Bars, using EMA, I want to find "The Real Bull and Real Bear Bar" present at the end of particular move. For that I have written code as shared here.

I am facing problem, when I want to use integer variable for 'offset' in 'Plotshot' and 'barcolor'.
I am getting warning - "A `series int` argument was used with `offset` in the `plotshape()` function, but only its last calculated value is taken into account. The parameter will only support `simple int` arguments in the future; consider eliminating `series int` use for `offset` arguments in your scripts." Resultant Bar color and plotshape taking to other bar then desired.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Idicator", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500)
var float ValidHigh = 0.0
var float ValidLow = 0.0
ValidHigh := high < ValidHigh[1] and low > ValidLow[1] ? ValidHigh[1] : high  < close[1] ? close[1] :    
 high
ValidLow := high < ValidHigh[1] and low > ValidLow[1] ? ValidLow[1]  : low   > close[1] ? close[1] : low
var float ValidBar = na
ValidBar := ValidHigh > ValidHigh[1] and ValidLow >= ValidLow[1] ? "Up" : ValidHigh <= ValidHigh[1] and      
 ValidLow < ValidLow[1] ? "Dn" : ValidHigh > ValidHigh[1] and ValidLow < ValidLow[1] ? "Out" : "In" 
var string Move = na  
Move :=  ValidBar == "Up" ? "Up_Move" : ValidBar == "Dn" ? "Dn_Move" : Move[1]
var float  M_Line = na 
MLine :=  ValidBar  ==  "In" ? na : Move == "UpMove" ? ValidHigh : ValidLow
UpTurn = Move == "UpMove" and Move[1] == "DnMove"
DnTurn = Move == "DnMove" and Move[1] == "UpMove"
var int UpMoveCount  = na 
UpMoveCount :=  ValidBar == "In" ? UpMoveCount[1] : UpTurn ? 1 : Move == "UpMove" and Move[1] ==   
 "UpMove" ? nz(UpMoveCount[1]) + 1 : na
var int DnMoveCount = na 
DnMoveCount  :=  ValidBar == "In" ? DnMoveCount[1] : DnTurn ? 1 : Move == "DnMove" and Move[1] ==  
 "DnMove" ? nz(DnMoveCount[1]) + 1 : na
EMA14 = ta.ema(close,14)
TheBull = ValidBar != "In" and EMA14[1] > ValidHigh[1] and EMA14[1] > ValidLow[1] and UpMoveCount == 1  
 and DnMoveCount[1] >= 3 
TheBear = ValidBar != "In" and EMA14[1] < ValidHigh[1] and EMA14[1] < ValidLow[1] and DnMoveCount  == 1 
 and UpMoveCount[1] >= 3
BarSinceLastDn = ta.barssince(MLine==ValidLow)
BarSinceLastUp = ta.barssince(MLine==ValidHigh)
//PROBLE START FROM HERE
plotshape(TheBull, style = shape.labelup, color = color.new(#00FF00,00), size=size.small, location =  
 location.belowbar, offset= - BarSinceLastDn)
plotshape(TheBear, style = shape.labeldown, color = color.new(#FF0000,00), size=size.small, location = 
location.abovebar, offset= - BarSinceLastUp)
TheBullColor = TheBull ? #00FF00 : na    
TheBearColor = TheBear ? #FF0000 : na
barcolor(TheBullColor, offset = - BarSinceLastDn, title = "Bullish DPB Candle" )
barcolor(TheBearColor, offset = - BarSinceLastUp, title = "Bearish DPB Candle" )
```